# Rails- Migration controller is not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I'm new to rails, my command:

```
bin/rails generate model database Date:date Endpoint:text User:string
```

Domain:string

into the command line which then generated:

invoke  active_record

```
  create    db/migrate/20150805174248_create_databases.rb
  create    app/models/database.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/database_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/databases.yml
```

and after I ran:

```
 bin/rake db:migrate
```

However, when following this tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html  SECTION(5.3)

When trying to save data to the controller/database it tells me to access  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb (articles being the variable name they used).

The problem I face is that databases_controller.rb was never created in the first place! Can anyone provide any insight? thanks!

**NEW QUESTION** The file databases_controller.rb is empty. I have created one before a few weeks ago and it was full with def index,new, edit, C,R,U,D. However this one is empty. As I'm supposed to add

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  @article.save
  redirect_to @article 
end
```

to the create portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the controller:

```
rails generate controller databases
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That step flew right passed me. Would upvote but not enough reputation yet!

Comment: @KennyEllis You can still press the checkmark right above the arrow because you asked the question. That's to "Approve" the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a newcomer to Rails, `Scaffolding` might be another handy option. `Scaffolding` can be used to generate some of the major parts of a Rails application such as models, views and controllers for a new resource.

```
rails generate scaffold Database date:date endpoint:text domain:string
```

That way, you don't have to worry about creating the models, views and controllers separately for your newly added resource.

Comment: Awesome! Great insight @Keen Learner!